# How to filter and populate second spinner based on first spinner with PHP and MySQL on Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, spinner, android-spinner

Please help!, How to use two spinner on android that second spinner data is filtered by first spinner with PHP & MySQL. im already set the second php url to filter the data, but i have no idea how to populate the second spinner with `doInBackground` ,`populateSpinner`, `onItemSelected` etc.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner spinnerFood;
    private Spinner spinnerFood2;
    // array list for spinner adapter
    private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
    private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList2;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int kabupaten;
    // API urls
    // Url to get all categories
    private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://192.168.1.88/android_spinnner/get_categories.php";
    private String URL_CATEGORIES2 = "http://192.168.1.88/android_spinnner/get_kelurahan.php?id_kabupaten=";
    private String URL2 = URL_CATEGORIES2+kabupaten;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinnerFood = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinFood);
        spinnerFood2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinnerFood2.setEnabled(false);
        categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();
        categoriesList2 = new ArrayList<Category>();

        // spinner item select listener
        spinnerFood.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinnerFood2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        new GetCategories().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Adding spinner data
     * */
    private void populateSpinner() {
        List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
            lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
        }

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerFood.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * Async task to get all food categories
     * */
    private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Fetching food categories..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if (jsonObj != null) {
                        JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                                .getJSONArray("categories");

                        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                            Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("id"),
                                    catObj.getString("name"));
                            categoriesList.add(cat);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            populateSpinner();
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position,
        long id){
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        kabupaten = categoriesList.get(position).getId();
        spinnerFood2.setEnabled(true);

    }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > arg0){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set OnItemSelectedListener for both the spinners in the same class, I have the following suggestions for you.

First inside the onItemSelectedListener, you have a parameter view. Using that find the Id (view.getId() ) and find which spinner it is. If it is the first spinner execute another AsyncTask to fetch the items for the second spinner.

One more suggestion is, 
In the async task Instead of using void, use the parameter to send the URL for which you are fetching the result, so that you can reuse the same code for fetching the details for both the spinners.

Comment: can you show me the code please? i think it wouldn't be a very long code... im really new to android programming..

Comment: can you wirte up your code in codepen or github and share the link ?

Comment: im uploaded the source code here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9SYHG43eWD7SlZjbTRQNWdXbDg

im include the php & database file there. thanks.